# Unable to kill process Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to kill processes on port 80. Here are the process running on port 80

```
lsof -i tcp:80
COMMAND  PID    USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nginx   6233    root   13u  IPv4 4216925      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   6235 opscode   13u  IPv4 4216925      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

I have tried killing processes using `kill -9 <PID>` but they still exist with PID changed. How can I kill the processes forcefully?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1):

Your question is better suited on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/) or [askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com).

But I think your problem is that you have an `nginx` daemon started.
You can stop it with either `systemctl stop nginx` if you are using *systemd* or `service nginx stop` if you are using *system V*